# Accessing Protected Page Using Javascript in Asp,NET MVC Returns Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to redirect a user to a controller action using javascript and I keep getting Unauthorized Response

The Java script Code is as follows

```
 var instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: this.baseUrl,  headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    });
    instance.post('Account/Login', d)
        .then(function(resonse){
            console.log(resonse);
            window.location = this.baseUrl + 'live';
        }).catch(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        window.location.href = this.baseUrl +'Account/Login';
    }.bind(this));
```

My Login Routine is implemented as follows

```
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    "A valid Email address and password is required");
            }

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Live");
                }  
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Account is disabled at the moment");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Email address requires confirmation");
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid Log in Attempt");
            }
        }
```

And the action method I am trying to redirect to is as follows

```
[Authorize]
public class LiveController : Controller
{

    [Route("live")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Now my issue is that when authentication is successful and I try to redirect to /live url, I still get Unauthorized response from server even though authentication was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `.ASPXAUTH` (or whatever you called it if you customized the name) cookie is being set. That's really the only thing that would make you look unauthenticated after just authenticating. An AJAX request *should* support the server setting a cookie, but there may be something weird at play.

That said, there's really no point in logging in via AJAX if all you're going to do is redirect immediately after. You could just as easily do a standard post with a `returnUrl` and achieve the same effect, and that definitely would work 100% of the time.